# Smoke not showing up in render?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I am using 3 layers, a tornado (flow physics particle), some text that was converted into mesh so it could explode and get sucked in by the tornado. I also have a surface plane which is the only thing that appears in render, except for a vague hint of a colourless tornado.

[image]

[image]

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/au6151h09mkc4tn/AAAaJZg0p62cMzvXyrbrmhj-a?dl=0) is the link to the blender file and two screenshots, I hope they will help show my problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) We like to keep questions focused to one topic here, which keeps things more organized and easier to search through for others with the same issues. Feel free to post as many questions as you want, by try to keep to one question per post. Thanks :)

Comment: Though note that most of your objects have their *render visibility* (camera icon) disabled in the *outliner*. You can quickly enable them all by clicking on the top or bottom camera icon, then dragging your mouse over the rest of them (this works on all toggle-able items in blender)

Comment: I guess that some users have made mess with density and density scale (in material tab) only density must be 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some odd reason the texture coordinates for your voxel texture are undefined:

[image]

Printing the value of the setting with python says that it's set to `global`, which is not the value you want anyway. Try setting it to *generated*.

For some reason I also needed to set the viewport *maximum draw type* to *textured* in order to get this to work in 2.72, which is extremely odd..

[image]

This was not needed in 2.69. I've reported this as a bug [here](https://developer.blender.org/T42441). It has been fixed as of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB3ea11c1ac8e7e30f986e23f5641ff043ecb6c62e), which will be in 2.73.

---

Also be sure to allow the voxel texture to influence the scattering color of the smoke, otherwise it will not be colored like you might expect:

[image]

Comment: Gandalf, when I posted this I didn't realisticly expect to get such a helpful answer so soon and in such a clear way! It solved my issue exactly as intended and I am impressed how fast you solved it, you got good blender logic I guess! Thanks a lot, I will definitely keep coming to this forum for future problems. I would upvote your answer but I need 15 reputation, which I don't have yet :) Anyway, thanks so much and good luck with your own projects!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which I wasn't aware until now and works in newer versions of the Blender for fire and smoke, is just to select the object, then click space, and type quick smoke. All the properties necessary for the smoke to show up in 3D view and render are all correct and all works like a charm in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late to answer the original question:
I experienced something comparable that neither smoke nor fire was shown. This happened because I used the simulation from frame 5000 to 6000 in my animation and per default the particle system as well as the smoke simulator work between frame 1 and frame 200. So if you change both values to your needs, smoke is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:  With the smoke domain selected, open up the mapping section of the voxel data texture, select coordinates, and set it to object.  A box should appear that lets you select an object.  Set it to the smoke domain.  Hope this helps!