# Can render smoke & fire in view port with [Alt A] but no fire and only smoke on render [F12]

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

I can't seem to figure out what setting I'm missing to render fire using blender render [F12]. Can anyone please push me in the right direction? Should I just follow a different tutorial rendering in cycles with the node editor and toss the blender render method? Would it even matter? I seem to be missing a step. I was following along a tutorial from someone using an older version, I believe version 2.6 but I'm not positive on that. I'm thinking something is different with the default settings from their version versus the latest greatest. I tried to catch it on my own in their settings while watching the tutorial but came up short.

Here is my problem,

I'm able to simulate the smoke and fire in the view port with [Alt A]. I'm able to bake it as well and render the view port but when I have a still shot of the flame and press [F12] for blender render I only see the smoke and not the fire.

Thank you in advance to anyone that goes out of their way to help me solve my problem.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18354/599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The texture for the domain object doesn't have any coordinate mapping set. Set it to `Generated`. Moreover, the colour ramp is a bit off. It has to be fully transparent to the left, or the domain will be completely filled with the left colour. The left is what appears further away from the flow object and the right is what appears closer to it. Personally I prefer to have it completely transparent at the right end as well, but that is my opinion and not a requirement. At the very least, you need to flip the direction of the ramp.
[image]

Furthermore, the `Flow type` on the flow object needs to be set, depending on what you want.
[image]

In the image it's set to `Smoke`. Available options are `Fire`, `Fire + Smoke`, `Smoke` and `Outflow`.

The first three should be self-explanatory. I have never fiddled with the outflow, but if it does the same as in the fluid sim, it should simply absorb the smoke and the flames.

If it is set to include fire, there's also a `Smoke flames` section for the domain object. If you want only fire and no smoke at all, you should set `Flow type` to `Fire` and set `Smoke` under `Smoke flames` to 0.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I have the (Flow type) set to "Fire". There are so many settings to consider. It seems this is going to be tough for people to help me without more detail of what I've already set. Hmmm How do I or can I send my .blend file so someone interested/willing can take a peek at it? Perhaps that's the way to go?

Comment: @chrisjohnson How did you set the sim up? Did you create it manually or did you use the Quick smoke? Did you create a material for the smoke domain? You can upload the .blend to pasteall.org/blend and edit your question to include the link.

Comment: I did all of it manually following a tutorial someone posted as a youtube video. I did it this way instead of just using "quick smoke" so that I can learn more about the settings and UI. I obviously need it. lol Yes, the domain cube is set up. I can press [Alt A] and see the simulation just fine with smoke and fire as expected. My only problem is when I click [F12] and I only see the smoke but not the flame. I will try to upload the .blend file. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Here's a tutorial that I found useful when I first started with smoke and fire. It uses the quick smoke and shows how to tweak the settings. http://youtu.be/i-IbKIdL1WQ

Comment: Ok so I uploaded the .blend to pasteall.org/blend. It was really unclear to me weather or not it actually posted though. There wasn't anything to identify me as a user and I didn't see any option to add a question. I'm feeling quite ignorant right now to say the least. I posted it as Flames_Practice.blend. I have no clue how to include a link to it. I don't know where the upload stores the file. I'm really sorry for my lack of knowledge. Thank you for your patience with me.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson If the file was properly uploaded, you should see the filename and a download link. In that window, simply copy the address from the location bar of your browser and post it here. There's no way to find a file there simply by its name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19698/discussion-between-sixthoffour-and-chris-johnson).

Comment: SixthOfFour has solved my problem. I need to go to my texture and change the color ramp to have zero alpha at both ends and most importantly under "mapping", I needed to set the coordinates to "generated". Problem solved.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson I uploaded a modified version of your file, with a material I used for a fire sim a while ago. The link is in the chat. Fiddle with it as much as you like, or use it as it is.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson if your problem is solved please post a detailed answer so others having the same issue can learn from your experience.

Comment: cegaton, I did post what the problem fix was. I needed to go to my texture and change the color ramp to have zero alpha at both ends and most importantly under "mapping", I needed to set the coordinates to "generated".

Comment: @cegaton I believe I may be to blame. I should have updated my answer with the solution the OP and I found while discussing this in chat. I have done so now.

Answer (score 0):

I see two things you need to change with your file -

1. Change the flow type to Fire + Smoke - this is on the plane emitting the flames.
2. Flip the colour ramp direction. This is the flame texture on the domain object.

There is a two headed arrow above the colour ramp that will switch directions for you. this may not give the result you want, the main point would be the alpha values used at each point in the ramp are the wrong way around.