# Smoke appears on viewport but doesn't in final render

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

I've followed [this tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24284/creating-inky-looking-characters-in-blender) (first highlighted answer), I've set the right volume material and voxel texture, have lights, etc... I've baked the smoke, it appears correctly in the viewport, exactly as intended in the 3d viewer. But as soon as I hit render, the smoke object doesn't appears at all.

Smoke used to work on my system, quick smoke is ok etc... I don't understand why in this case it doesn't, do you have any clues?

Comment: Have you read the similar (possibly duplicate) posts by others having problems getting smoke to render? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33356/smoke-is-not-appearing-in-cycles-render?rq=1 http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18354/smoke-not-showing-up-in-render?rq=1

Comment: Thx for your answer, yes, I have, but these does not resolve my pb :)

Comment: Actually, I don't understand, maybe a bad manipulation, because after a few tries, it does work !
I'll post the result in a few minutes.

Comment: [http://i.giphy.com/l41lXd4N1NPox3OVO.gif]

Comment: Hey, that looks pretty awesome! Does this mean your problem was resolved?